# Python development in VS code shows errors when there are none?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

[image]

I have python installed and set in the PATH variable. I've also installed the Python interpreter from the VS code extensions. The code runs, when I run it but it keeps showing these linting errors.

pip automatically installed pylint. I'm not sure what else I'm doing wrong here. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: When defining a function you still need to include `()` parenteses, hence the unexpected token and indent errors.

Answer (score 0):

A function definition needs a specification of parameters - if you have none, it still needs `()`.

So:

```
def solve():
    print(3)


solve()
```

Also, add an extra linefeed between the function and the main body, it's good to follow PEP8 as you're learning, to develop a good style.

Comment: So I've always used jupiter notebooks to do python, for data science and such. I've never been taught to use the parentheses. Is that a new rule? Also can you give me a link to such rules like the parameters etc.

Comment: Oof, that question is so basic, I actually had trouble finding it in the documentation, but this is it: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions  From that article: "The keyword def introduces a function definition. It must be followed by the function name and the parenthesized list of formal parameters." It's been like that for as far as I can remember in Python though.

Comment: Parentheses as part of a `def` line to specify arguments have always been required by Python.